# Expressing a function in terms of an infinite series involving its derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $G\left(x\right) = \int{g\left(x\right) \,dx}$, therefore:

$$\int_{a}^{b}{g\left(x\right) \,dx} = G\left(b\right) - G\left(a\right) = \left(b - a\right)\lim_{N \to \infty}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{g\left(a + \frac{n}{N}\left(b - a\right)\right)}}$$

Let $g\left(x\right) = f'\left(x\right)$:

$$f\left(b\right) - f\left(a\right) = \left(b - a\right)\lim_{N \to \infty}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{f'\left(a + \frac{n}{N}\left(b - a\right)\right)}}$$

Let $b = x$:

$$f\left(x\right) = f\left(a\right) + \left(x - a\right)\lim_{N \to \infty}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{f'\left(a + \frac{n}{N}\left(x - a\right)\right)}}$$

I believe this would be valid for $f\left(x\right)$ differentiable on the interval $(a, x]$.

(1) Let $a = x_{0} : f\left(a\right) = 0$:

$$f\left(x\right) = \left(x - x_{0}\right)\lim_{N \to \infty}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{f'\left(x_{0} + \frac{n}{N}\left(x - x_{0}\right)\right)}}$$

(2) Let $a = 0$:

$$f\left(x\right) = f\left(0\right) + x\lim_{N \to \infty}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{f'\left(\frac{nx}{N}\right)}}$$

Using (2), let $f\left(x\right) = \ln\left(1 + x\right)$:

$$\ln\left(1 + x\right) = x\lim_{N \to \infty}{\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{\frac{1}{N + nx}}}$$

which yields that, for $x = 1$:

$$\ln\left(2\right) = \lim_{N \to \infty}{\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{\frac{1}{N + n}}}$$

Although this formula requires a lot of terms to reach even a few significant figures of accuracy, I think it is beautiful to think that such a constant can be represented in such a consise way.

My question is, is this derivation correct? And, if so, would any results from this be at all useful, given that the rate of convergence is so slow?

**ADDITION**

$$\int{\frac{f\left(x\right) - f\left(a\right)}{x - a} \,dx} = \int{\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x - a} \,dx} - f\left(a\right)\ln{|x - a |} = C + \lim_{N \to \infty}{\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{\frac{1}{n}f\left(a + \frac{n}{N}\left(x - a\right)\right)}}$$

Let $a = 0$:

$$\int{\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x} \,dx} - f\left(0\right)\ln{|x|} = C + \lim_{N \to \infty}{\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{nx}{N}\right)}}$$

Let $x = Nt$, $N \to \infty$:

$$\int{\frac{f\left(Nt\right)}{t} \,dt} - f\left(0\right)\ln{|Nt|} = C + \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{\frac{1}{n}f\left(nt\right)}$$

Let $f\left(x\right) = 0$, therefore $C = 0$:

$$\int{\frac{f\left(Nt\right)}{t} \,dt} - f\left(0\right)\ln{|Nt|} = \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{\frac{1}{n}f\left(nt\right)}$$

Comment: Your derivation looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The derivation is indeed correct.

Note that we can verify independently that $\log(2)=\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n+N}$ without appealing to Riemann sums.

To do so, we write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{N+n}&=\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac1n\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac1n-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac1n\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac1n\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right) \tag 1\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n-1}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (-x)^{n}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1-(-x)^N}{1+x}\,dx \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Note that upon taking the limit as $N\to \infty$ in $(2)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{1-(-x)^N}{1+x}\,dx &=\int_0^1 \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\frac{1-(-x)^N}{1+x}\right)\,dx\\\\
& =\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx\\\\
&=\log(2)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!  The interchange of the limit and the integral can be justified by applying, for example, the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

---

> To answer the question in the OP regarding speed of convergence, note that the form in $(1)$, upon taking the limit as $N\to \infty$, provides an absolutely convergent series that has terms that behave as $\frac{1}{2n^2}$ for large $n$.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you so much for taking the time to make this post!

Comment: You're welcome!  It was my pleasure.  -Mark